# retrofit is not public in retrofit2.retrofit android studio

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I'm having these lines of code

public class RetrofitClient {

```
private static Retrofit retrofit=null;

public static Retrofit getClient(String baseUrl)
{
    if(retrofit==null)
    {
         retrofit = new Retrofit().Builder()
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

    }

    return retrofit;
}
```

}

and i'm getting this error...

> error: constructor Retrofit in class Retrofit cannot be applied to given types;
>   required: okhttp3.Call.Factory,HttpUrl,List,List,Executor,boolean
>   found: no arguments
>   reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

If i put my cursor on the error Retrofit i can see that it says

**Retrofit(okhttp3.....)is not public in 'retrofit2.retrofit'.Cannot be accessed from outside package**

Any help please?

Answer (score 2):

You should be correct you code as below mentioned.

```
public class RetrofitClient {
    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;
    public static Retrofit getClient1(String baseUrl) {
        if (retrofit == null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok my bad... I should have used `Retrofit.Builder()` instead of `Retrofit().Builder()`.